# Can one apply for a Schengen visa while visiting the Uk as a tourist?

Tags: visas, schengen

My husband  and I together with our 9 month old son wish to visit Portugal  when we visit the UK  in 4 months  time , however we are resident in St Helena island , a British oversees territory . Our biggest challenge is that  there is no consulate of any country on the island . Can anyone have information on how  we can apply these visas . Thank you.

Comment: What are the nationalities of the travelers?

Comment: I am looking on the website of the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.portaldiplomatico.mne.gov.pt/en/), and it does not appear to identify the consular district to which St. Helena Island belongs.  The logical conclusion then is that you *should* apply in the UK.  But the [VFS pages for the UK](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Portugal/UK/Tourist.html) maintain that applicants there must reside in one of several UK counties.  You'll need to find out which consulate St. Helena has been assigned to, which if it isn't one in the UK will most likely be one on the west coast of Africa.

Comment: At one time there was a French consulate in Jamestown. Is it no longer there? France still has it listed as an [active consulate](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/le-ministere-et-son-reseau/annuaires-du-ministere-de-l-europe-et-des-affaires-etrangeres/ambassades-et-consulats-francais-a-l-etranger/article/ambassades-et-consulats-francais-a-l-etranger), at Longwood House, telephone 24409. If it is actually open, you should be able to apply for a Schengen visa there.

Comment: Also note that if you have a British Overseas Citizen passport you don't need a visa to visit Portugal anyway.

Comment: Thank  you  very  much  for  your  responses . We are Zimbabwean nationals  and we are none holders of British overseas passports.  The French consulate is not open anymore here.